# How to encrypt a live rootfs on Arch Linux

Tags: ssh, encryption, arch-linux, lvm, systemd

I have a Linux Arch system running on a VPS. The rootfs is installed on a LVM partition. I would like to overlay an encrypted container on this partition, then reinstall the rootfs on it and enable ssh unlock at boot via ssh. I am happy to discard all content of the existing rootfs and create a new one from scratch.

I am trying to proceed as follows:

1. create a new temporary rootfs in /tmp/newroot
2. chroot to it
3. at this point I would like to completely stop all services still hanging on to the old root, which is on the lvm partition (one of which is sshd itself), and restart them from the new root
4. create an encrypted partition on the lvm partition
5. install arch Linux on it and modify intrafms appropriately

For 1 and 2 I am using the archlinux bootstrap image provided in the arch [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_from_existing_Linux#From_a_host_running_another_Linux_distribution). 4 and 5 are well documented (for instance [here](https://gist.github.com/pezz/5310082)).

I am stuck with step 3. After I chroot, using *fuser* I can see there are lot of processes still hanging to the lvm partition, which do not allow me to overlay an encrypted container on top of it, and I am not sure about how to stop them and restart some of them from the new root. *Kill* executed from the original root stops them, but before I do that! I should restart some of them from the new root (e.g. sshd), otherwise I will cut myself out. I tried to start them from the new root with *systemd*, but it does not work because it detects that we are in chroot mode. I tried to launch them via the command line, and no error is generated, but when I search the processes with *ps*, they are not there.

Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

And if anything went wrong during steps 4 and 5 you would end up with unbootable system. Does your VPS have 100% availability guaranteed?

If "live" (or online) reencryption were not a requirement, `cryptsetup-reencrypt` could handle offline reencryption. All it would require is extending the LV. There is a work in progress to allow live reencryption but this is far from stable. The additional space requirement will stay, as there are not many filesystems allowing online shrinking.

If using additional disk space is an acceptable solution, you could create a LUKS encrypted physical volume, add it to the volume group and use pvmove to move rootfs away from unencrypted device.

I do not think there is a simple solution to move to encrypted LV.

Comment: The VPS offers a backup-restore service. So every time I do something wrong, I can restart from scratch.

Comment: Availability is 99.5%, but that would be good enough. I would not mind from time to time to have to login and decrypt it when reset by the system.